# Correct use of @media?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm finishing up work on a website I've made, but it requires some separate CSS code for different resolutions.
This is what I currently have in my .css file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) (max-width: 1366px) {
.button{
    background-color: blue;
}
}
```

The background color for buttons is the only element I have for now, to test if the code works or not.
But obviously, it does not, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Simply said: what I want to do is change that background color of buttons to blue if the resolution is between 1000px and 1366px of width.

All other CSS works so the link with the HTML page is correct, and the .button class works as well.

What should I change in this code to come to this?

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1366px) {`

Comment: For more breakpoints check this one http://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

Comment: an additional thing to consider when using media queries for screen sizes is to change the max/min by + or - 1px to include/exclude sizes exactly the way you intend. Firefox's "responsive design mode" is a useful tool to test this.

Answer (score 2):

> A **media query** consists of a media type and at least one expression
>   that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as
>   width, height, and color. Media queries, added in CSS3, let the
>   presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output
>   devices without having to change the content itself.

### Correct code :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .button{
        background-color: blue;
     }
}
```

[Some example of media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers, seems it was much more simple than I thought.
Adding an "and" between the two widths and using -1px on their values has helped me.